formula to count in how many cells first digit is greater than second in last pair
Let's say I have row of cells A1:A10 with values like "46 64 76", "63 60" etc. Two or three pairs of digits separated by spaces. I need to count in how many cells in last pair first digit is greater than second.

Try the following approach:
Find the last space in A1 and save the position in B1:
=FIND("###";SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"###";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";""))))

Remove the last number vom A1 and save the value in C1:
=VALUE(MID(A1;B1;LEN(A1)-B1+1))

Remove the last number from A1 and save the string in D1:
=LEFT(A1;B1-1)

Find the last space in D1 and save the position in E1:
=IFERROR(FIND("###";SUBSTITUTE(D1;" ";"###";LEN(D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D1;" ";""))));1)

Remove the last Number from E1 and save the value in F1:
=VALUE(MID(D1;E1;LEN(D1)-E1+1))

Now compare F1 and C1 and save the value in G1:
=F1>C1

Repeat for all rows.
Now count all values in column G that are true:
=COUNTIFS(G:G;TRUE)


Get Count
The example checks each row in the range A1:G10
=SUM(BYROW(A1:G10, LAMBDA(r,
    1*LET(v,TOROW(r,1), b,INDEX(v,1,COUNTA(v)),
    LEFT(b,1)>RIGHT(b,1))))))

Functions Used
BYROW  COUNTA  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEFT  LET  RIGHT  TOROW
Explanation

Uses BYROW to pass each row of your range into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in r
The LAMBDA's formula uses LET to store values in variables for reuse:

v stores the result of applying TOROW to r. r is already a row, but this allows discarding any empty columns with minimal code.
b stores the last pair from the row by applying INDEX to r using the column count from r (which no longer includes empty columns) to identify the last column.
With the last pair in b, it is split using LEFT and RIGHT and they are tested to see if the left digit is larger returning TRUE or FALSE.


Let the result be multiplied by 1 to coerce the TRUE and FALSE strings to 1's and 0's.
Once all rows r are processed, the resulting array of ones and zeros is added using SUM which results in a count of those rows where the last pairs' left digits were greater than the right ones.

Get Count and Total
Variation to return the total count of rows.
=LET(rng,A1:G10, 
  {"Count", "Total"; 
  SUM(BYROW(rng, LAMBDA(r,
    1*LET(v,TOROW(r,1), b,INDEX(v,1,COUNTA(v)),
    LEFT(b,1)>RIGHT(b,1))))), ROWS(rng)})

Get Count and Percentage
Variation returns the count and the percentage UT represents.
=LET(rng,A1:D10, 
  num,SUM(BYROW(rng, LAMBDA(r,
    1*LET(v,TOROW(r,1), b,INDEX(v,1,COUNTA(v)),
    LEFT(b,1)>RIGHT(b,1))))),
  {num,num/ROWS(rng)})

